# Standing/sitting practices of an instructor

Tags: teaching, statistics, lecture-teaching-method

[A question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41322/what-are-the-health-impacts-of-standing-sitting-while-lecturing) on this site deals with health aspects related to the posture while delivering a lecture.

My question is about the statistics regarding the same practice and its effect on students.

In general, the success of a lecture may depends on several factors like lecture notes, interactivity etc. Is standing/sitting (of an instructor) in classroom one among them? Does it effect teaching success in any way? Are there any stats related to it?

I know about some institutes having an explicit rule that an instructor should not sit while delivering a lecture and they provide neither chairs nor tables. Is this rule implemented in the institutes of many countries?

Note that sitting or standing by an instructor in this question refers to the instructor who either sits or stands throughout the lecture or at least 90% of the lecture.

Comment: This is by no means a complete answer, so a comment. But, consider actors who want to be dramatic and hold the audience. How often do you see an actor performing while seated? Unless the staging requires it (a king on a throne for example) they are on their feet.

Comment: "I know about some institutes having an explicit rule that an instructor should not sit while delivering a lecture" - may I ask for examples, out of curiosity? This just sound ridiculous.

Comment: Lot of private colleges in India @sleepy It is common here.

Comment: I get it if you replace "sit" with "sleep".

Answer (score 7):

> Does it effect teaching success in any way?

Effective teaching engages with students.  If there are many students, you cannot engage with all of them effectively from one place.  For example, I walk to the part of the room where students are not paying attention; then they start paying attention.  I do not recommend either standing still or sitting still; sitting in a moving wheelchair would work fine, though.  That's not quite what you asked for, but it works.

> Is this rule implemented in the institutes of many countries?

I've never heard of it.  I think this rule would be illegal in countries that protect workers with disabilities.

Comment: I didn't answer the part about statistics.